# Amazon upgrade RDS connection fails

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, rds

I recently changed the size of my Amazon RDS instance size from micro to small. After it was finished, I could no longer login from workbench. I have been using the database all day and there have been no issues until now. I tried resetting the master password and rebooted the database as well. If anyone has any guidance on why I can no longer access the database. I created a small application and had been using it to add information to the database for hours. The endpoints and other information remain unchanged except instance type. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Show the complete error including any numeric codes you see when trying to connect.  Guesswork should not be required.

Comment: 10060 was the error code.

Comment: Error 10060 is [Connection timed out](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668(v=vs.85).aspx).  This rules out password related problems, and is telling you that the server is not accessible at all -- it is not refusing to allow you to connect.  When upgrading a non-multi-AZ instance, several minutes will pass without the instance being accessible.  This is expected.

Comment: It took over an hour for the instance to be accessible again. I have no idea why, but that's what happened. The other post on Stack Overflow said it could take up to 20 minutes but mine took at least an hour. I tried for over an hour and then took a four hour nap and it worked when I woke up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you allow me to share my story, my problem is even more strange: I could login with MySQL Workbench, but cannot query and export data. I tried logging out and then log back in, but it failed, even though I never had changed any settings and especially the password. My final solution was to change the master password and Apply that change immediately.

It is possible that there's something happened behind there that I could not possibly understand.

Try and check your RDS Instance's setting if resetting password did not work, especially the `Security Group Rules` setting under `Network & Security`. Then make sure that `Public Accessibility` setting is set to `Yes` if you are trying to access it from outside your VPC. Also try to restart your MySQL Workbench if after resetting and re-inputting your password does not work immediately.

Comment: I had tried a few of those. I am attempting to change the password again and see if that does anything. I restarted workbench. Public accessibility has been yes for a while now. I am doing it all over again in hopes that something fixes itself. I guess time will tell.

Comment: No, even after trying all of it again, it did not work. I cannot connect with workbench or through my application. I have been using both all day without problems and it wasn't until I increased the size of the database (I needed to establish more connections for higher speed).

Comment: That's rather weird, but I can only tell you to re-check all the settings and instance details again, VPC, subnet groups and all that. Another thing you can try is to try post this problem on AWS Forums or create a support ticket. I'm sorry I can't be much help on this.

Comment: I was up for an hour after I switched the database to a larger size. Amazon responded with the same things we discussed and said it could take up to twenty minutes. I have a feeling it can take longer than 20 minutes because it works fine now.

Comment: Nice! Glad to hear it's working. But apparently I also skipped a very similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4832459/aws-rds-instance-upgrade-down-time?rq=1. It makes sense if it takes a little long if you had more data inside your database instance.